# Adding the ng-class on the angular material chips

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, material-design, angular-material

I want to create border for the chips based on my key value type for which I have made a ng-class="classEmployeeType($chip)" .. it works fine if i add it to any fixed dom element,  but md-chip is created on page load. How to add this ng-class on dynamically created dom element.

**html**

```
<md-chips ng-model="ctrl.listVal"
      md-autocomplete-snap md-transform-chip="$chip" md-require-match="ctrl.autocompleteDemoRequireMatch">
                        <md-autocomplete>
                            <md-item-template>
                                // custom autocomplete functionality
                            </md-item-template>
                        </md-autocomplete>
                        <md-chip-template >
                            <span>
                                <strong>@{{$chip.name}}</strong>
                            </span>
                        </md-chip-template>
                    </md-chips>
```

**CSS**

```
 .add-key-chips .md-chips .md-chip{
    border-radius:2px;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #027cd8;
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height:18px;
    top:7px;
    padding:0 5px;
    color: #027cd8;
    }
```

Comment: Elements added dynamically must be compiled in angular i think. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile Could you show the code that adds the element in page load?

Comment: its angular material chips, that add the dom element  "md-chip" inside <md-chips></md-chips>

Comment: So it's a directive then? Do you have control over the template? If so, you can just add `ng-class` there? Have you tried to just add it directly on `<md-chips ng-class="..."></md-chips>` btw?

Comment: its not working if I am adding directly, as the class has to be added in <md-chip></md-chip> only

Comment: And what about all the other things i asked about?